# Create a query for SQL Server into multiple tables and order the result in the form of the tree relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
1) id1, name
2) id2,name,id1
3) id3,name,id2
```

I'm looking for help to compose a query for SQL Server that will return a result ordered in form of an expanded tree - like:

```
t1.id1
 t2.id2
   t3.id3
   t3.id3
   t3.id3
 t2.id2
   t3.id3
   ...
```

All `id` fields are unique identifiers, so in result table I want to get just 2 fields - `ID,Name`

Comment: Can you show us what kind of data you have in your tables? Just two or three sample rows will be sufficient...

Comment: 5e6389cd-8175-4573-8a0d-123bbfe057dc Category1 NULL NULL NULL NULL 1 680614d7-da43-4f22-97aa-0f7c45452898

Comment: first unique id is an id of t2, last unique id is the id of the parent from t1

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL can not do that. You can't return a tree in that way - all rows are similar, meaning the column in each row comes from the same table.

You could however program something to do that.